# Hyperledger Fabric transaction endorsement with different requirements

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a theoretical question.

Let's say we have a transaction that needs endorsement by 2 peers. But the two peers have different requirements to endorse a transaction. For example if we want to change the value of the number N, for peer 1 it will endorse it only if the value is higher than 5, and for peer 2 it will only endorse it if the value is higher than 10 (I know it doesn't make a lot of sense this example but... let's say it's like that).

What is the way to split that logic in the chaincode? How to understand on which peer the chaincode is executed at the moment so I can check if the value should be over 5 or over 10 in order to endorse it?

Answer (score 3):

You can support that in v1.1 if you install a custom [authentication filter](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L345-L360) in the peer(s) that will parse the proposal and deny it in some cases.

Basically you create a .so file and put the reference in core.yaml and then the peer loads with it.

Take a look at an [auth filter](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go) that checks for the expiration of the client's certificate.

Comment: That's nice! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, two questions comes from here for me:
1) in the sample it is just said `name: ExpirationCheck` but it doesn't say where the file is, how the .yaml knows where to look?
2) Is it possible to define on which chaincode I want this filter to work? As far as I understand that will filter all chaincodes

Comment: 1) We have 2 types of auth handlers - those that are compiled with the peer (expirationCheck is such) and those that are loaded as plugins. 
Take a look at the core.yaml, it shows both of the plugin types and how to configure them.
2) no, but I opened https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8370 which I want to get into v1.2 :)